# How do I resue a function in another function?

Tags: python, function

I have created a function in python to print the square value of a list's elements as shown below:

```
def square_list(list1):
    lst = []
    for i in list1:
        lst.append(i*i)
    return lst

x = [2,4,6,8]
print(square_list(x))
```

This is the output `[4, 16, 36, 64]`

I would like to reuse this function again as shown below:

```
n = [2,4,6,8]
print(list(map(square_list,n)))
```

But it shows this type of error as shown below:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-9c542410d2fa> in <module>
      1 # list=[m,n,p] + f()==> Map ==> modified list = [f(m),f(n),f(p)]
      2 n = [2,4,6,8]
----> 3 print(list(map(square_list,n)))

<ipython-input-79-51bec1661935> in square_list(list1)
      1 def square_list(list1):
      2     lst = []
----> 3     for i in list1:
      4         lst.append(i*i)
      5     return lst

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

May you please tell me where is my mistake and explain to me?

Comment: shouldn't you call ```print(square_list(n))``` instead of ```print(list(map(square_list,n)))```?

Comment: I'm using map function and map() must have at least two arguments.

Comment: your function expects a list, and you give it an int instead (because you're calling it from map). if you have to use map no matter what, then try ```print(list(map(square_list,[n]))[0])```

Comment: @Kristian It works. Thank you so much. But what does this [0] mean? Second thing I allocate a list to n, it means n has a list, why did it consider it as an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map()` iterates over the list and passes each element to the function. That means the function needs to accept the individual elements of the list, not the list itself. You can't use the same function for both. `map()` simplifies the function to just:

```
def square_list(n): 
    return n * n

n = [2,4,6,8]
print(list(map(square_list,n)))
# [4, 16, 36, 64]
```

because it takes care of the iteration as part of the process.

Comment: Note that the new function definition will not work for the first test case in OP's question.

Comment: Thanks @12944qwerty - I think that's what I was getting at with "You can't use the same function for both". Was that not clear?

Comment: YES sir, that's what I have done above in def square_list(list1), this function will deal will list, then after that, map with iterates over the list. I'm using the same idea. But you passed only an element in your function (def square_list(n): ), am I right?

Comment: Yes, map operates on each element of the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the same function for both cases, you can check the type of the parameter.

```
def square(x):
    if type(x) is list:
        lst = []
        for i in x:
            lst.append(i*i)
        return lst
    return x * x
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/TU1FWC)